# Web scraping using transients

Tags: php, transient

I'm using xPath to scrape tour dates from another website (with permission of course). Since it updates on every page load, I thought about using transients to store the data.

Unfortunately I have no experience using transients and don't get it to work. This is my code:

```
<?php
  $html = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com');       
  $doc = new DOMDocument();

  libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); // disable libxml errors

  if(!empty($html)) {

    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors();

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    // Get only the content needed
    $termine = $xpath->query('//ul[@class="artistEvents"]/li');            

    if ($termine->length > 0) {
      foreach ($termine as $termin) { 

        $date = $xpath->query("div[@class='left']/strong", $termin);
        $location = $xpath->query("div[contains(@class,'right')]", $termin);

        echo '<tr>';

        // Date     
        if ($date->length > 0) {
          $date = substr($date->item(0)->nodeValue, 3, 10);
          $date = strftime("%d.%m.%Y", strtotime($date));
          echo '<td class="live-date">' . $date . '</td>';
        }

        // Location
        if ($location->length > 0) {
          $location = substr($location->item(0)->nodeValue, 14);
          $location = utf8_decode($location);
          echo '<td class="live-location">' . $location . '</td>';
        }

        echo '</tr>';
      }
    }

    else {
      echo '<p>No dates available.</p>';
    }

  }
?>
```

Any help with how to use transients to store this query is greatly appreciated!
Also, I've never used xPath before, so if my code needs any improvement (although it works) I'll be happy to know about it.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Since you have permission, doesn't this "other site" have a better way for you to get content than scraping the site?

Comment: I wish they would, but the answer is no. They have no RSS feed or the like for the dates and are not planning to implement it.

Comment: ouch! That is rough. Exactly where does your code fail?

Comment: It doesn't really fail, the code works. I just don't know how to modify it to store the scraped data using transients, so the data doesn't update on every page load.

Comment: I don't see any transient code at all?

Comment: It's not in there yet, sorry if I was ambiguous about that. I want to extend the code so that I'm able to store the scraped data, but don't really know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this, which would save in transient for 12 hours. Let me know if anything does not make sense.

```
<?php
$value = get_transient( 'value' );
if ( false === $value ) {
  $output = "";
  $html = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com');       
  $doc = new DOMDocument();

  libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); // disable libxml errors

  if(!empty($html)) {

    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors();

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    // Get only the content needed
    $termine = $xpath->query('//ul[@class="artistEvents"]/li');            

    if ($termine->length > 0) {
      foreach ($termine as $termin) { 

        $date = $xpath->query("div[@class='left']/strong", $termin);
        $location = $xpath->query("div[contains(@class,'right')]", $termin);

        $output .= '<tr>';

        // Date     
        if ($date->length > 0) {
          $date = substr($date->item(0)->nodeValue, 3, 10);
          $date = strftime("%d.%m.%Y", strtotime($date));
          $output .= '<td class="live-date">' . $date . '</td>';
        }

        // Location
        if ($location->length > 0) {
          $location = substr($location->item(0)->nodeValue, 14);
          $location = utf8_decode($location);
          $output .= '<td class="live-location">' . $location . '</td>';
        }

        $output .= '</tr>';
      }
    }
    else {
      $output .= '<p>No dates available.</p>';
    }
  }
  $value = $output;
  set_transient( 'value', $value, 12 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );

}
echo $value;
?>
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: One last question: Is it possible to modify the output of the transient once it's stored?
This example doesn't seem to work:
`$value = str_replace("Text1", "Text2", $value);
echo $value;`

Comment: That should work. Don't see any reason why it wouldn't

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work in the first place but now it does. Thanks again, I really appreciate your help!